# Uniqueness of Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform

The theorem for Uniqueness of Laplace transform is as below:

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions. If $Lf(s)$ = $Lg(s)$ then $f(t)$ = $g(t)$.

I am following the proof given in the notes in the following link:

http://web.mit.edu/jorloff/www/18.03-esg/notes/laplaceuniqueness.pdf

By following the proof in the above notes, I have proved the Lemma for it, which says that

> If $h(u)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $\int_{0}^{1} h(u)u^ndu=0$ for $n= 1, 2, ...$ then
>   $h(u) = 0$.

In the proof of the above theorem, I have omitted the proof from the start, it's easy and you can go through it in the link provided above. The last equation of the proof is:

> $0 = Lf(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)e^{-nt}e^{-s_0t}e^{-t}dt=\int_{0}^{1} u^n(u^{s_0}f(- \ln(u)))du$

As you can see, here the function $h(u)$ is $u^{s_0}f(-\ln(u))$. When Lemma is applied, we straight forward got $u^{s_0}f(- \ln(u)) = 0$ as mentioned in the notes. We also have to prove that this $h(u)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. i.e; $u^{s_0}f(-\ln(u))$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and to prove the continuity of this function, we have to prove the continuity of $\ln (u)$ as well in the interval $[0,1]$, whereas we know that $\ln(u)$ is undefined at $0$. How will we get away with this singularity problem at lower bound of interval $[0,1]$. i.e; at $0$.

Your earliest response will highly be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the last sentence in the notes of any help ?

Comment: @Sary, many thanks for your response. As I described earlier, I have to prove $h(u)$ = $u^{s_0}f(- ln u)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, or we can also say that $!u. 0<=u<=1 => (\u.u^{s_0}f(- ln u))$ is continuous at $u$. We also know that $h(u)$ is multiple of $u^{s_0}$ and $f(- ln u)$. For the case of continuity at $u=0$, we know that $u^{s_0}$ is continuous, but $f(- ln u)$ is not continuous due to singularity created by $ln u$.

Comment: @Sary, the last sentence in the notes can only be helpful, if at $x=0$, $!u. 0<=u<=1 => (\u.u^{s_0}f(- ln u))$ is continuous at $u$, results into $!u. 0<=u<=1 => (\u.0^{s_0}f(- ln u))$ is continuous at $0$, so the function h(u) will result into 0 which will be continuous which is false. Whereas it will result into $!u. 0<=u<=1 => (\u.u^{s_0}f(- ln u))$ is continuous at $0$. So to prove its continuity, we have to remove this singularity for ln u.

Comment: Your sentences are very unclear. Let $k(u) := u^{s_0}f(-\ln u)$. By assumption, $|f(t)|<Me^{at}$ for all $t$ (I think there's a typo in the notes -- should have absolute values there). So for $u>0$, you have $|k(u)|=|u^{s_0}f(-\ln u)| < Mu^{s_0-a}$. But $s_0>a$ by assumption, so the RHS tends to 0, so $k(u)$ also tends to $0$ as $u\to0$. So alsthough the function $k$is not defined a priori at $0$, you can extend it to a continuous function by setting $k(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the condition that $f$ is of exponential order. That is, $\vert f \vert \leq M e^{ct}$ for some $c, M \geq 0$. With this condition your problem can be solved by some transformation: To show $f = 0$, it's equivalent to show on $[0, \infty]$, $e^{-c_1t}f = 0$ for some $c_1 >> c$ but fixed. Then easy to see that $e^{-c_1t}f$ is in $L^1[0,\infty]$. Now for simplicity we may assume $f \in L^1$ and continuous (by previous transformation). So $f(-ln(u))$ is in $L^1[0,1]$. Then Lebesgue's Theory tells us the integral won't change after taking out a single point of Lebesgue measure $0$, namely, $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ (or you can say original $f$ vanishes at infinity, so $f(-ln(u))$ vanishes at $0$). Then apply the lemma (or you can do extension at $0$ as $0$, then apply the lemma).

Actually there's a simpler way, namely, $\textbf{The Stone-Weierstrass Theorem}$, saying that $H = \lbrace e^{-\lambda t}: \lambda\geq0\rbrace$ forms a dense subset up to uniform norm in continuous function space of $\mathbb{R}\cup\lbrace \infty \rbrace$ (one-point compactification), by the same transform method above, we want to show $g = fe^{-ct} = 0$, easy to see that $g \in L^1 \cap C_0(\mathbb{R})$. Since $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(t) \phi(t) dt = 0$, $\forall \phi \in H$, pick $\phi_n \to g$ in uniform norm, apply $\textbf{Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem}$ we shall see that $\int_{0}^{\infty}g^2(t) dt = 0$, thus $g = 0$ a.e., but $g$ is continuous, results follows.